# SQL Server SELECT Rank() and Grouping of data

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by, rank, with-statement

Please help me with this specific query.

Here's my sample query

```
with cte as 
(
select entryID,LogDateTime,logtype[logtype],batch,
rank() over (partition by logType 
           order by logdatetime) rnk
from Emp_TimeLog
where cast(LogDateTime as date) = '2016-05-17'
) select entryID,LogDateTime,logType,batch, rnk 
from cte order by LogDateTime
```

It resulted like this

```
2016-05-17 11:57:44.000 1   1   1
2016-05-17 11:57:53.000 5   1   1
2016-05-17 11:57:58.000 6   1   1
2016-05-17 11:58:10.000 2   1   1
2016-05-17 11:58:18.000 1   2   2
2016-05-17 11:58:25.000 3   1   1
2016-05-17 11:58:32.000 4   1   1
2016-05-17 11:58:42.000 5   2   2
2016-05-17 11:58:49.000 6   2   2
2016-05-17 11:58:55.000 2   2   2
```

But what I want is like this.

```
2016-05-17 11:57:44.000 1   1   1
2016-05-17 11:57:53.000 5   1   1
2016-05-17 11:57:58.000 6   1   1
2016-05-17 11:58:10.000 2   1   1
2016-05-17 11:58:18.000 1   2   2
2016-05-17 11:58:25.000 3   2   2
2016-05-17 11:58:32.000 4   2   2
2016-05-17 11:58:42.000 5   2   2
2016-05-17 11:58:49.000 6   2   2
2016-05-17 11:58:55.000 2   2   2
```

The last 2 columns are the `Batch` and `Rank`,
while the 3rd column is the `logType`.
it should be group by batch of `logType` wherein `LogType` group is 1,2,3,4,5,6.
so, for every 1 group it is another batch and I need to place it on last 2 columns.

Please help with this, on how I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your query, `batch` is the actual value in a record. But you want to have a result with different `batch` value.

Comment: please, add sample data/table

Comment: Yes, I should group it by batch of 1,2,3,4,5,6. 
in my example above, 
first batch should be 1,5,6,2. (even its not complete)
second batch should be 1,3,4,5,6,2. 

I should look and based on the 3rd column.
please help

Comment: can you label the column of your expected result set ? It is a bit confusing on what you want to group by. From your description and the expected result, it seems like it does not conincide

Comment: the last two column should be the result

Answer (score -1):

You just need to fix the order in the rank... as:

```
rank() over (partition by logType 
           order by batch) rnk
```

Comment: no sir, it didn't work. I'm just relying on the 3rd column because the last 2 column should be the answer of what i want the result.

Comment: it should be order by the date and time.

Comment: You can leave the order of the main select `by LogDateTime` but inside the rank it should be batch